# AngularJS adding Headers in http.put request

Tags: angularjs, http

I am new to angularJs, right now I want to use $http.put to update an Json file at a remote repository.

but everytime I try, I get the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blabla&action=update. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So it doesn't work. now I did my part of search on Stack and google. a lot of people are saying I should add headers. I don't know how to add headers correctly and I have no idea how to verify if the headers are correctly added.

Can someone help me? The following is my code.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
$http.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT';
$http.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Credential'] = 'true';
$scope.update = function(key,value){
    $scope.myData[key] = value;
    $http.put('http://blabla&action=update', $scope.myData)
    .success(function (data, status) {
        alert('success');
    })
```

the code above is still giving me the same error, from my research online, the headers are suppose to solve this problem... but it didn't. I don't know what I did wrong. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the headers need to be set on the server.  Your error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.` is the key to all of this.

You are requesting from localhost:9080 to somewhere like foo.com/api.  That endpoint needs to return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:9080` header to your application.

Comment: So I need to ask the server side to return that to me?

Comment: Yes if you are able to.  These headers are part of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) and it's a security feature.  Basically an agreement between you and a backend server and that you both expect and allow each other to send and get data from each other.

Comment: i will try that once that person get back from lunch

Comment: You might have to add more CORS headers but this will be the first one.  It really depends on what you are doing.  But Chrome should continue to give you relevant error messages about what headers are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a config object to the `$http.put` method like this:

```
$http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://blabla&action=update',
        data: $scope.myData,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "self",
            <other headers here>
        }
    })
    .success(function (data, status) {
    alert('success');
});
```

And you can verify the headers with the request within developer tools if you use Chrome or IE and FireBug if you use Firefox.
More info on [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: But if the call fails by the above error, I cannot see the headers in developer tools. Therefore I cannot know if the headers are correctly added